# The BDLPSWDKS Effect

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7352/48337) and is based on https://xkcd.com/1531/.</sub>

---

Dear Puzzling Stack Exchange,

This is in response to your request dated July 16, 2022, under the Freedom of Information Act seeking access to records related to the BDLPSWDKS effect.

Based on the information you provided in your letter, we conducted a thorough search of our agency's various systems of records, and we have located and reviewed 1 panel of records.

Portions of this panel fall within one of the 9 exemptions to the FOIA's disclosure requirements, and their redactions are annotated with their respective numbered exemptions.

If you have any questions, please contact me in the comments below.

Sincerely,

noedne

[image: xkcd comic with redactions]

Comment: Argh, I NEED to know where this well is >:(

Comment: @LukasRotter If you are not satisfied with this response to your request, you may appeal by writing to the FOIA Appeals Officer within 90 days of the date of this letter.

Answer (score 12):

This has actually become the BDLPSWDKS**S** effect because it suffers additionally from the

> [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect), i.e., hiding some information has increased the chance of it becoming publicly known.

We can find this in the picture by

> counting which word is redacted on each row and taking the corresponding letter from the name in the BDLPSWDKS effect as indicated in the censor bar. I.e., since the first word is censored on the first row and the censor bar indicates Sapir, the fifth name, we take the first letter of Sapir. Doing this gives,
>
>  **S**apir
>  S**t**roop
>  Who**r**f (this name is redacted but can be found in the original)
>  Krug**e**r
>  Bernoull**i**
>  Leidenfro**s**t
>  Peltzm**a**n
>  Dun**n**ing
>  **D**oppler
>
>  spelling out **STREISAND**.